# Should I keep my Idoneal earings?

Tags: tera

I have a set of Idoneal earrings, which have an Item Level of 179.

Everyday I find all sorts of earrings with varying Levels, but they are all around Level 168.

People recommend me to get the Frostwise Hoops because of the +2% of healing skills.
I get those from VOA (Vault of Alliances) and from Solo Vault.
Since I'm a mystic, it actually makes sense, but I have a whole lot of +2% healing skills' status on all the other gear, and the extra MP, HP, Item Level and the damage are really helpful.

Should I keep my Idoneal earrings or change to Frostwise?

(Here is a helpful list, with the level 65 jewelry: http://forum.teratoday.com/topic/465-level-65-jewelry-stats/)

Comment: The set bonuses are always better than individual item stats. As a mystic, you need as much % healing as you can get for when you are healing, but there's nothing wrong with having two sets of jewelry, one for healing and one for soloing/dps'ing in small parties.

Comment: @Chippies I know, but one has inferior everything, while the other only has a tiny less % healing. One saved my a$$ a few times on BAM fights, the other would be my death. That is, using them separately. Imagine the disaster that would be when healing on Bathismal Rise and then that crab 'pukes' that green thing everywhere, taking a huge chunk of my HP. Or being 1-hit by the last boss.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what the stats on Idoneal earrings are, so it's hard to say for sure. If the difference is slightly more healing vs being able to survive harder dungeons then stick with the one that gives you more survivability. A dead healer doesn't heal.

Comment: @Chippies I guess you are right. Thanks for the comment.